# z-index problem with helper clone

Tags: jquery

This is my code (please see http://jsfiddle.net/VCfSc/1/):

```
$('.first').draggable({
    cancel: null,
    helper: 'clone'
});

$('.second').droppable({
    over: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).css('z-index', 1);
        ui.helper.css('z-index', 0);
    }
});
```

I am trying to have the helper clone go *under* the droppable element when it is dragged over it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you drag the `.first` element, the generated draggable element is positioned absolutely *and* added after the `.second` element. An absolutely positioned element gets a higher precedence. To fix this, use `ui.helper.css('z-index', "-1");` instead of  `ui.helper.css('z-index', 0);`.

Comment: *"An absolutely positioned element gets a higher precedence"* = breaks your code. Atributing a negative z-index can be translated to *"Don't throw me up, I am not important"*.